# Possible GUID corruption/issue between c# mvc sqlserver nhibernate and querystring

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have GUIDs, pulled from a database into a model. That model is then used with a razor view to populate and send emails.

The GUIDs (along with a few other pieces of information) are passed from the emails into an MVC controller, and all seems fine - most of the time.

I started logging all .net exceptions on the MVC site, and started noticing multiple exceptions of: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

With each error I also store the current HttpContext Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, for example on one of the errors:

```
mysite.com?/Topic/89/ArticleEmailed/52077?userguid=e6ea4f65-95421868-4441150d-b12c-99ce87bc95bd
```

Notice that is not a 32 digit GUID. I looked that user up in the database, and found the value that would have been used in the email, which is a valid 32 digit:

Value stored in database: E6EA4F65-9542-444D-B12C-99CE87BC95BD

Field type: uniqueidentifier (SQL Server 2008)

The "corrupt" value being passed into the site has an extra 8 digits, as shown below. The top line is what came back into the MVC controller, and the bottom line is what i confirmed the value to be in the database.

I've added spaces where the differences are to make it easier to read. There is an extra "1868" and an extra "1150" in the middle of the guid, which of course causes guid.parse to fail (case sensitivity is not an issue).

```
e6ea4f65-9542 1868 -444 1150 d-b12c-99ce87bc95bd
E6EA4F65-9542      -444      D-B12C-99CE87BC95BD
```

Code involved:

Model A, populated from the database via nhibernate:

```
public virtual Guid GuidId { get; set; }
```

Model B, used in the email, populated from model A:

```
public string UserGuid { get; set; }
```

using:

```
model.UserGuid = user.GuidId.ToString();
```

The line in the razor view, sent as email:

```
<a href="SomeFullPathUrltoController?userguid=@(Model.UserGuid)">
```

There are several other data points used in the model/view that come through with no issue, it's only this GUID that I'm having issues with.

Maybe because it's Friday I'm just missing something simple, but I'm not seeing it...I've done different tests and a good amount of online research.

Comment: What does the HTML for the anchor look like?

Comment: The full exact one it uses is: <a href="http://@(Model.Domain)/Topic/@(a.TopicId)/ArticleEmailed/@(a.Id)?userguid=@(Model.UserGuid)" target="_blank">  and everything else comes through as expected

Comment: Not quite clear what the problem or your question is. Could it just be a user who was bored, or one with a really weird proxy, mail client or firewall? MVC doesn't magically mangle URLs for only one GUID.

Comment: It happens 6-12 times per day, and it's always different users/domains. I guess I'll leave exception logging enabled and if this turns out to be a small percent overall may have to write it off...

Comment: Maybe you can also log the HTML that is generated for the e-mail for some time so that you can check which link is really sent to the user.

Comment: Yeah Markus I'm adding logging to everything used by the SMTP client to send, I'll have more results on Monday morning.